# Can't create 3d surface with dataframe plot_ly

Tags: r, dataframe, plotly

I have been trying to create a 3d surface with plotly but I couldn't. What I did is the following:

```
dataf <- data.frame(x=as.numeric(1:50), y=as.numeric(1:50), z=as.numeric(1:5))
```

And then

```
plot_ly() %>% add_trace(data = dataf,  x=dataf$x, y=dataf$y, z=dataf$z, type="mesh3d" )
```

But the problem is that it prints me an empty graph.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `plot_ly(z = as.matrix(dataf), type = "surface")`

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure @SBista produces the desired graph. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783676/r-plotly-3d-surface-plot-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1 instead.