# Cannot create a 3D surface using plot_ly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, surface, r-plotly

MWE: a dataframe shown below.

```
"TVF" "minEuler" "E_avg"
29.63 -12 3.65
30.00 -26 3.311
30.24 -72 8.247
30.82 -47 13.02
20.25 -6 2.085
14.53 -32 2.154
14.66 -1 1.44
24.12 -82 6.784
21.25 -35 4.309
25.82 -17 2.697
26.15 -42 2.832
18.38 -29 2.038
18.51 -80 5.514
14.67 -58 1.91
20.40 -166 2.786
26.50 -69 6.794
40.97 -12 24.852
18.98 -102 3.107
19.15 -75 3.85
40.54 -48 16.347
35.09 -41 18.847
28.15 -73 5.963
40.25 -94 21.82
24.28 -53 6.245
30.34 -42 25.578
```

CODE:

```
plot_ly(x = S_TVF_Euler_E_axes$TVF, y = S_TVF_Euler_E_axes$minEuler, 
        z = S_TVF_Euler_E_axes$E_avg, type = 'surface')
```

OUTPUT:

[image: No surface is created]

GOAL: Fit a surface to the scatter plot (or directly plot a surface). I could plot the scatterplot using `plot_ly` but the surface isn't working.
I have tried also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449817/cant-create-3d-surface-with-dataframe-plot-ly), which did not work for me.

I am new to 3D plots and any help or hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess I was in a haste to post it, but later on figured out how it can be done. Plotly is quite different than ggplot2 in data types & commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by s_t, we need to have a matrix for plotting the surface. I tried a little different way, using the `interp` function from the package `akima`. I got the idea from the answer by "mschilli" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783676/r-plotly-3d-surface-plot-issue).

```
> S_TVF_Euler_E_axes_plotly <- with(S_TVF_Euler_E_axes, interp(TVF, 
                                  minEuler, E_avg, duplicate = "mean"))
> plot_ly(x = S_TVF_Euler_E_axes_plotly$x, y = S_TVF_Euler_E_axes_plotly$y, 
        z = S_TVF_Euler_E_axes_plotly$z, type = 'surface')
```

[image: Surface only]

Now, I am worried if my surface is right or wrong, it doesn't match at all to the solution provided by s_t!

Comment: TBH it seems your solution's better, and mine wrong, so I'll delete it. You can compare your with `plot_ly(S_TVF_Euler_E_axes, x = ~ TVF, y = ~minEulerM, z = ~E_avg) %>% add_markers()` to see if they are similar.