# How to plot a 3d surface with plot_ly?

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have this dataframe that I want to plot in 3D.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5rr8doqny65665/mprob.csv?dl=0

I managed to plot the datapoints, but now I would like to plot a 3D surface. I tried adding add_surface() but it did not work. What am I doing wrong? Could someone help me with a code? Adding contour lines would be also nice...

```
p <- plot_ly(mprob, type = "scatter3d", mode="markers", x=mprob$var1, y=mprob$var2, z=mprob$ec, color = mprob$ec)  %>%
  layout(
    title = "Empirical copula",
    scene = list(
      xaxis = list(title = "Negated TTC [s]"),
      yaxis = list(title = "Relative Speed [m/s]"),
      zaxis = list(title = "Probability")
    ))
p
```

The error message that I received:

```
Error in UseMethod("layout") : 
  no applicable method for 'layout' applied to an object of class "character"
> p
Error: `z` must be a numeric matrix
```

Comment: It would be more convenient for us if you added the dataframe in your post (with `dput`), in order to help you. What do you mean by "*it did not work*" ? Do you get an error message? An unexpected result?

Comment: Try using `plot_ly(data=mprob, x=~var1, y=~var2, z=~ec, color=~ec, type = "scatter3d", mode="markers")`. The plot is a 3D scatter plot, not a 3D surface plot.

Comment: What kind of surface do you want? Do you have a link to an example? I don't see how to plot a surface with a cloud of points in 3D.

Comment: I think I found what I wanted: bivariate interpolation using the akima package.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783676/r-plotly-3d-surface-plot-issue